# Having trouble adding msecounds to this as3 code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, 2d-games

Hi everyone I have a code snippet I am tring to add to my flash game. It works fine I am just having trouble getting it to display milisecounds. Any help would be great!

```
function formatTime( time:Number ):String {
var remainder:Number;
var hours:Number = time / ( 60 * 60 );
remainder = hours - (Math.floor ( hours ));
hours = Math.floor(hours);
var minutes = remainder * 60;
remainder = minutes - (Math.floor ( minutes ));
minutes = Math.floor(minutes);
var seconds = remainder * 60;
remainder = seconds - (Math.floor ( seconds ));
seconds = Math.floor(seconds);




var hString:String = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours:"" + hours;
var mString:String = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes:"" + minutes;
var sString:String = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds:"" + seconds;
if (time < 0 || isNaN(time)){
    return "00:00";
}
if (hours > 0)  {
    return hString + ":" + mString + ":" + sString;
}
else{
    return mString + ":" + sString;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get milliseconds, you want to take fractional part of `time`, it's done like that:

```
var mseconds:Number=Math.floor((time-Math.floor(time))*1000);
var msString:String=(mseconds<10) ? "00"+mseconds :
        (mseconds<100) ? "0"+mseconds : ""+mseconds;
```

Then you add that to your formed string.